# BinaryFormatter not serializing field

Tags: c#, serialization, xna-4.0

I am having a little trouble getting BinaryFormatter to actually serialize this one field.

I have a Tile class and I serialize it's position and ID, I then save all these tiles using the BinaryFormatter. Every one other field is non serialized and is initialized using the value of the ID.

However, the ID field just won't serialize but everything else does. What could be the cause of this?

Here is my Tile fields:

```
        // The ID of this tile
    private int id;
    // The name visible for the tile in the map editor
    [NonSerialized] private String name;
    // The file location for this tile for loading a texture
    [NonSerialized] private String fileName;

    // Sprite for drawing this tile
    [NonSerialized] private Sprite sprite;
    private Transform transform = new Transform();

    // If this tile is blocked, blocked tiles can not be walked over are classes as "unpassable"
    [NonSerialized] private bool blocked;
    // Used to determine if a specific tower types can be placed on this tile, if any
    [NonSerialized] private short towerMask;
    // The tower that is placed on this tile, if any
    [NonSerialized] private Tower tower;
    // A path generated for enemies to navigate from this tile to another, used for tiles that can spawn enemies
    [NonSerialized] private Path path;
```

When I load the map, I do this:

```
            map = MapSerializer.Load("test");
```

And the MapSerializer class is just the usual setup, with a static load and save method like so:

```
        public static Map Load(string filename){
        Map map;
        String path = Path.Combine("maps/", filename+".mp");
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        try{
            Trace.WriteLine("Loading map from " + path, "Map Serialization");
            map =  (Map) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            Trace.WriteLine("Map Loaded!", "Map Serialization");
        }
        finally{
            stream.Close();
        }

        return map;
    }
```

The other annoying this is, when the tiles are loaded it does not call the no args constructor. What is with that? I have to manually loop through all the tiles and call Create(), despite it is called in the no args constructor.

Any ideas that one int field is not writing to disc?

EDIT:

Serialization code:

```
 public static void Save(Map data, String filename){
        String path = Path.Combine("maps/", filename + ".mp");
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        if (!Directory.Exists("maps"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory("maps");
        FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create);

        try{
            Trace.WriteLine("Writing map to " + path, "Map Serialization");
            formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
            Trace.WriteLine("Map Saved!", "Map Serialization");
        }
        catch (SerializationException e){
            Trace.WriteLine("Failed to save map : Error - " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally{
            // Close the file
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the serialization code?

Comment: That looks ok. How do you initialize the ID field in the Tile class?

Comment: 2 ways. In the map editor I create all the template tiles by calling a constructor that takes the ID, it then uses this ID to pick the correct parameters for the rest of the class.

The second way is when actually placing/changing tiles on the map, I simply do Tile tile = template.Clone() and it returns a new tile with the same ID.

All I have checked in every part of my code that deals with the creation of tiles, they are all using the correct ID at the time. If they were not, they would have all sorts of messed up parameters, like the texture; which reflects the tile type just fine.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. In fact when i run a binary formatter serialization on tiles it works. Check out the code i use at http://rextester.com/THW45627 (you will not be able to run it online.. im just sharing the code)

Comment: @Gibbo In the serialization code you are creating the formatter, but not using it, is this correct? `BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();`

Comment: Whoops my apologies, I had started a new branch to give some other serializers a shot, at the moment I have Protobuf working correctly. The problem still exists with BinaryFormatter. Will fix the op.

Comment: If you are persisting these serializations to disk BinaryFormatter is a very bad choice, it handles version changes to types being serialized very poorly. A windows update could leave you not being able to open the files you previously saved. BinaryFormatter should really only be used for IPC within the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted the serialisation code. To your second issue ...

The serialisation will not call your default constructor. If you implement ISerializable then the constructor taking the serialisation specific arguments will be called.

An alternative is to implement System.Runtime.Serialization.IDeserializationCallback. For details see here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Another alternative is by decorating a method with the [OnDeserialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered the IDeserializationCallback shortly after posting, that is one issue fixed.